# Get Names of TreeView Elements

Tags: python-3.x, treeview, pywinauto

How can I get the names of treeView elements?

```
treeView = addDevWin.TreeView
node2= treeView.GetItem([u'Parent', node1'])
node2.select()
level3nodes = node2.children()

# Output:
#[<pywinauto.controls.common_controls._treeview_element object at 0x068C8750>, <pywinauto.controls.common_controls._treeview_element object at 0x068C82F0>, <pywinauto.controls.common_controls._treeview_element object at 0x068D2750>, <pywinauto.controls.common_controls._treeview_element object at 0x068D2870>, <pywinauto.controls.common_controls._treeview_element object at 0x068D2770>]
```

I want to obtain the names of the treeview element objects like they appear in the UI. So that I can select them as follows:

```
for element in level3nodes:
    if 'substring' in element:
        node3= treeView.GetItem([u'Parent', node1', element])
        node3.select()
```

Using : Windows 10, Python3.

Answer (score 1):

You need method `.item_texts()` for `treeView` object. Tree view items in "win32" backend are kind of virtual items that don't have usual Win32 API handle. That's why you need `.get_item(...)`

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that worked:

```
treeElemList = [u'Parent', node1']
treeView = devWin.TreeView
node2= treeView.GetItem(treeElemList)
node2.select()
level3nodes = node2.children()
for element in level3nodes:
    if 'substring' in element.text():
        treeElemList .append(element.text())
        break

node3= treeView.GetItem(treeElemList)
node3.select()
```